# change font size for category's description in woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an issue with font-size of categories descriptions, they are so small I need to make the font bigger
I have tried the below CSS but it didn't work

```
.woocommerce .woocommerce-loop-category__description {
    font-size: 50px !important;
}
```

see the image of the category's description, its too small .. I need it to be bigger and bold:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5AXn.png)

any help with that please?

Comment: Can you please give URL to the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
.term-description {font-size: 50px !important;}
```